# unintended replacement in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have hundreds lines of text like this:

> `gi|393925858|gb|AGTA02071966.1|    0000000739    .    G    A    121.20    PASS    NS=74:AN=2:DP=8448    GT:DP:GQ:EC:SG    0/1:262:144:116:R`

I wanted to ONLY replace the colon with semicolon in this portion "NS=74:AN=2:DP=8448" of the line. Here is how  I matched and replaced it:

```
if re.match(r'.*NS=\d+(:)AN=\d(:)DP=\d+.*', line):
    print line.replace(':', ";")
```

I thought I just replaced the matched pattern in all lines, but it replaced EVERY colon with semicolon in all lines, is there a way to specify just the matched ones, or my regular expression was incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't you have to use the actual pattern in `.replace()`?  Right now it just checks to see if the line qualifies and replaces all.  You want it to check and then replace *using* your pattern.  Also what flavor of regex?

Comment: Use a regex.replace_all() style with find `r'(.*NS=\d+):(AN=\d):(DP=\d+.*)'` replace '\1;\2;\3`

Comment: Thank you, I imported re for pattern match. I do not quite follow your first suggestion, I wanted to only match something in "NS=74:AN=2:DP=8448", do you think my match pattern is too broad?

Comment: Right now, when it finds `NS=74:AN=2:DP=8448`, it replaces all `:` in the line: `NS=74:AN=2:DP=8448 GT:DP:GQ:EC:SG 0/1:262:144:116:R
`

Comment: thank you, if i understood correctly, why 're.sub(r'(.*NS=\d+):(AN=\d):(DP=\d+.*)', "\1;\2;\3", line)' would not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the full regex in the replacement, using capture groups (parentheses) to capture the digits you want to keep.

So your search term is this:

```
NS=(\d+):AN=(\d+):DP=(\d+)
```

And your replace term is this:

```
NS=\1;AN=\2;DP=\3
```

Note that in the replacement, the `\1` will be filled in with what the first capture group (parens) captured from the original text.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am still learning to code the regular expression in python, would you mind show me how to do this in python?